# Quick HS level questions about how functions work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a really hard time understanding these ideas about functions. Can you help me? Thanks for your patience!!

**Question 1**

If $f(x) = g(x^2)$ for all $x$, does that mean that $f(x)$ and $g(x^2)$ both must be constants? Because there is no way to construct functions for $f$ and $g$ that work for all $x$... correct?

**Question 2**

If $f(x) = g'(x)$ for all  $x$, then they both could be a constant (ie $0$) or they could be both $e^x$ which is not a constant. Is that correct?

**Question 3**

If $f(x) = g(x+1)$ for all $x$, then does that mean $f(x)$ and $g(x+1)$ do NOT have to be constants? They could be right, for example they both equal an arbitrary constant $c$? Or if $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x - 1$ then they are not constants and that works for all $x$

**Question 4**

In general, what are the conditions for $f(x) = g(h(x))$ to must be a constant?

Comment: None of these are correct.  For example, if $g(x) = x^3$, then $f(x) = g(x^2) = (x^2)^3 = x^6$, which is not constant.  There are two basic ways that $f(x) = g(h(x))$ can be constant: (1) $g(x) = c$ for all $x$ or (2) $h(x) = c$ for all $x$.  More generally, we would need $g$ to be constant on the range of $h$.

Comment: For question $1$, $g(x)$ is any function. Then $g(x^2)$ is a function that does not have to be constant. Then you define a new function $f$ by the rule $x\rightarrow g(x^2)$, in other words $f(x)=g(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x)=x$, then $f(x) = g(x^2)$ for all $x$ and is not constant.
2. Not completely. Solving the differential equation $y'(t)=y(t)$ we obtain $y(t)=Ce^t$ for any constant $C$. You only found $C=0$ and $C=1$.
3. Correct. They can be constant, but indeed they do not have to be.
4. We need $g\circ h(x)$ to be constant, that means that $g$ must be constant for all $h(x)$, so $g$ must be constant on the range of $h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, they are most beneficial!!! I will meditate on this.